# Migrating Storybook to 6.4 err: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

I have been following the multiple guides and troubleshooting online while migrating storybook to the newest version. I get this error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
resolve 'path' in '\node_modules\@storybook\store\dist\esm'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: \node_modules\@storybook\store\package.json (relative path: ./dist/esm)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      \node_modules\@storybook\store\dist\esm\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      \node_modules\@storybook\store\dist\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      \node_modules\@storybook\store\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      \node_modules\@storybook\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      \node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in \node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: \package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/path)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.jsx doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.cjs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              \node_modules\path.tsx doesn't exist
        \node_modules\path doesn't exist
      C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\dev_workspace\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\MyUser\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/store/dist/esm/index.js 10:0-28 10:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/angular/dist/ts3.9/client/preview/decorateStory.js 22:14-41
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/angular/dist/ts3.9/client/preview/index.js 17:38-64
 @ ./node_modules/@storybook/angular/dist/ts3.9/client/index.js 13:16-36
 @ ./node_modules/cypress-storybook/angular.js 1:0-50 7:2-15 14:2-15
 @ ./.storybook/manager.js
```

As suggested by the error itself and by different people who had the same issue (although not in storybook), I added path-browserify and put it on the main.js.

```
module.exports = {
    "stories": [
        "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
        "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "addons": [
        "@storybook/addon-links",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials"
    ],

    "core": {
        "builder": "webpack5"
    },
    "resolve": {
        "fallback": {
            "path": require.resolve("path-browserify")
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is still there unfortunately. This is the relevant part of my package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
        "@angular/forms": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/material": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "^12.1.1",
        "sb": "^6.5.0-alpha.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.1",
        "@angular/elements": "^12.2.11",
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
        "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.15",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/angular": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.8",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.8",
        "path-browserify": "^1.0.1"
}
...
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue and managed to resolve it? Thank you

UPDATE

---

I was able to remove the error at compilation time by removing the resolve property from main js and add the following code:

```
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
        "path": require.resolve("path-browserify")
    };
    return config;
}
```

But it didn't seem to effectively fix the issue, as when storybook loads in the browser throws this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path'
    at webpackMissingModule (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:129662)
    at Object../node_modules/@storybook/store/dist/esm/autoTitle.js (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:129662)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.manager.bundle.js:23)
    at Object../node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/preview/index.js (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:105440)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.manager.bundle.js:23)
    at Module../node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/index.js (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:105342)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.manager.bundle.js:23)
    at Object../node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/cjs/index.js (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:108560)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.manager.bundle.js:23)
    at Object../node_modules/@storybook/core/client.js (vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-actions_dist_esm_register_js-node_modules_storybook_addo-bf0ff2.manager.bundle.js:108542)
```